# linq circular query reference c# on Category and Parent Category

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, circular-reference

The category table have a circular reference to have an unlimited hierarchy structure.
Herewith is the structure im trying to achieve.
How do I write a query in linq C# to achieve the following structure ?

```
Automotive - vehicle hire 
           - Vehicle Sales
Tyre's And Shocks - Tyres  - dunlop
                           - continental
                  - Shocks - Gabriel
                           - No Name
```

[image]

```
var category = _context.Category.Where(c.ParentCategoryId == 11).ToList();
```

Table Structure :

| CategoryID | ParentCategoryID | CategoryName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | Automotive |
| 2 | 1 | Vehicle Hire |
| 3 | 1 | Vehicle Sales |
| 4 | 1 | Spares or Accessories |
| 5 | 1 | Automotive Associations |
| 6 | 1 | Financial Institutions |
| 7 | 1 | Health Care |
| 8 | 1 | Panelbeaters |
| 9 | 1 | Auto Glass |
| 10 | 1 | Mags or Rims |
| 11 | 1 | Tyre's And Shocks |
| 12 | 11 | Tyres |
| 13 | 11 | Shocks |
| 14 | 11 | Exhausts |
| 15 | 11 | Suspension Springs |
| 16 | 12 | Dunlop |
| 17 | 12 | Continental |
| 18 | 13 | Gabriel |
| 19 | 13 | No Name |

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: How do I write a query in linq C# to achieve the following above structure ?

var category = _context.Category.Where(c.ParentCategoryId == 11).ToList();